# How to perform Protractor testing in md-option

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, angular-material, md-select

I have the code in angular which is

```
<md-input-container> 
  <label>Country </label>
    <md-select name="country" ng-model="country"required >
     <md-optgroup label="Select Country">
      <md-option ng-repeat="item in countryList"  ng-value="item" >
                 {{item.countryName}}
         </md-option>
       </md-optgroup> 
     </md-select> 
</md-input-container>
```

and in have used the code in Protractor as following

```
 element(by.model("country")).click();
 browser.sleep(2000);
 element.all(by.repeater("item in countryList").row('1')).click();
```

and I am always getting the game error as

> Failed: element not visible

in the code the ***element(by.model("country")).click()*** is working fine but not selecting the md-option in popup window
please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code (You should get 1st element selected.

```
 element(by.model("country")).click();
 browser.sleep(2000);
 element.all(by.repeater("item in countryList").get(1)).click();
```

If still facing issue You can try to scroll till that element.

```
         element(by.model("country")).click();
         browser.sleep(2000);
         var elementToSelect = element.all(by.repeater("item in countryList").get(1));
         browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)',elementToSelect.getWebElement());
         elementToSelect.click();
```

Comment: I have tried this code but it gives error **Failed: elementToSelect.getWebElement is not a functio**. Then i changed the get() to row() i got error as **Failed: elementToSelect.getWebElement is not a function**